# How do I figure out what exactly is being called by /usr/bin/snap?

Tags: snap

Say for example I have `certbot` snap installed, and I want to figure out what happens when I call `certbot --help`. First I check what bash calls when I type `certbot`:

```
$ type -a certbot
certbot is /snap/bin/certbot
```

Then I check where /snap/bin/certbot points to:

```
ls -l /snap/bin/certbot
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Feb 18 18:33 /snap/bin/certbot -> /usr/bin/snap
```

/usr/bin/snap is just a binary:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/snap
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 23618992 Feb  2 08:21 /usr/bin/snap
```

So I suppose /usr/bin/snap figures out what to call based on how it was called. But how do I find out what exactly is being called after that? (e.g. is it `python /snap/certbot/952/main.py`, or something else?)

Comment: how about strace?

Comment: @Comar Yes, strace works, but I rather hoped for a less nuclear solution :)

Comment: @Comar inspecting strace output hinted at the answer: one can find the snap configuration in SNAP_DIR/meta/snap.yaml, and that file contains the command used when launching the app. For example for certbot file was located at /snap/certbot/952/meta/snap.yaml.

Comment: Just do it like me and don't use snaps, or at least use snaps only to the absolute minimum. Because snaps are just lazy implementations of software used by lazy developers and lazy system admins, which do more bad than good in the long time.

Comment: @paladin - I'm on your side, definitely :) I use snaps only when absolutely necessary (for example recent certbot versions can't be installed in any other way). But it seems that the general trend direction is towards lazy devs, so I'm gradualy preparing for the inevitable dark future of bloated hard drives and unpatched dependencies.

Comment: I'm not using Ubuntu any more cause of that reason. It's just silly. I find it acceptable when a developer maintains its snap like for example Visual Code or Nextcloud, but in my opinion it's broken that snaps aren't able to directly access the host filesystem, for example a data folder. This makes managing the software even harder. Also the systemd implementation is silly. Snaps look great in the beginning, but wait when your system has 20+ snaps, it's a nightmare. I've read that the calc app is also a snap because it uses internet access for currency calculation. Really? Just silly program.

Comment: @paladin - some snaps can access the filesystem, you just need to install them with "classic" flag.

Comment: @paladin I only use Ubuntu on my servers, and I don't see a good replacement at the moment. In server space it's currently either Ubuntu or some sort of RHEL, which is not cheap. On dev machines I use Arch, but it would be suicide to run Arch on production servers =)

Comment: I use debian stable as server os. Should I need something more modern, I add a backport or use a self compiled version. But usually I stick to stable and wait for the next stable. Less trouble. And I use mostly systemd for managing everything. PS SUSE might be a cheap alternative to RHEL.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments point out, I found the `docker` executable like this:

```
user@machine:~$ cd /snap/docker
user@machine:/snap/docker$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Aug 22 12:06 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Mär  4 17:11 ../
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root  335 Jun  8  2020 471/
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root  173 Feb  5  2021 796/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    3 Aug 22 12:06 current -> 796/
user@machine:/snap/docker$ ls -la current/bin/ | grep docker
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  85055920 Feb  5  2021 docker
```

So for me it was:

```
michael@thinkpad:~$ /snap/docker/current/bin/docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build cd8016b6bc
```